# Identity 2.0 using Membership Provider Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I am currently working on a .Net MVC project and Identity 2.0 but I need to be able to get user information from an Asp.Net Membership Provider Database. I have found several forums and articles on **Migrating from Membership Provider to Identity** but the problem is there are other application relying on that data and are still using Membership Provider so migrating is not really an option. Has anyone attempted this or came across someone that has. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement `IUserStore` to lookup users and implement `PasswordValidator` to be able to read password hashes in MemebershipProvider format.